# Headphone sound doesn't work and hangs a lot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04

I have both Windows and Ubuntu installed on my laptop. I have a strange problem, when I plug in the headphone in the jack while running Ubuntu, it does work. But when plug it in the jack while running Windows, it doesn't work. The external sound work well in both OS. Any

Another problem, when using the internet, the laptop hangs after 30 minutes of use and a black screen appears so I have to restart the laptop or hibernate it. What is the solution?
that doesn't happen when using Ubuntu.

A bad thing happen with Ubuntu, there are no videos working online on youtube or any other website although I'm installing flash player.what is the solution?

Comment: Have you went into the Windows sound mixer and checked that non of the volumes are mute and all of the volumes are up and your device is set to headphone?

Comment: yes i did and it was working and you know that green line going up and down showing the voice played, it was working as well

Comment: I've solved the sound problem, simply downloaded the configuration from DELL website for sound driver then installed it, it works now, there still two unsolved problems